# How to check last login date and purchase item date of customer

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I need to generate reports for customer who did not logged-In in `past 3 months` and yet not logged in after register on my website.

Also which have not purchase anything yet from my website even after logged in recently.

I need that data for maintain customer relation.

Here is my code .

```
<?php 

    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    umask(0);
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

    $version = Mage::getVersion();
    echo $version ."\n\n";

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();
    $lastVisited = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastVisited);

?>
```

I am using

> Magento 1.7.0.2 version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the database table log_customers, this has login and logout dates on all registered users.  The only problem you might have is if you have log cleaning enabled in

```
system > configuration (top menu)
advanced > system (left menu)
```

'log' (central area), this is where you configure log lifetime.  If you are going to use this for reporting, you could adjust this to requirement.

Using the data from the log_customer table, cross referenced with customer_entity (entity_id field), you will be able to generate the reports without touching the mage application.

Comment: As we didnt maintain user log before can we still get this data from somewhere from database?

Comment: if you didnt maintain it, then the data will be there.  it logs until told not to ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Get Last Login date:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection();
foreach($collectin as $customer){
   $logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
   $lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();
   echo $lastVisited = $customer->getFirstname(). " => ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastVisited). "<br>";
}
```

To show this result in admin area, I would create a simple admin extension: [learn here](http://inchoo.net/magento/getting-started-with-building-admin-module-in-magento/).

And put above code in controller for quick view, however I want you to understand how MVC works in magento and show desired result in magento way.

Comment: I am familiar with MVC architecture but not understanding where to start building and what / how I can start building desired extension. Bcoz now days everyday we want some new functionality to improve eCommerce store.

Answer (score 0):

Please use my below code then you will get customer login and logout time with customer id.

```
$model = Mage::getSingleton('customer/customer');$customerCollection = $model->getCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*');$customerCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array("t1" => 'log_customer'), "e.entity_id = t1.customer_id")->group('e.entity_id');
echo $customerCollection->getSelect();

foreach($customerCollection as $customerObject) 
{       
    echo '<b>CustomerID='.$customerObject->getData('entity_id').'Login At-'. $customerObject->getData('login_at').' Log Out at'.$customerObject->getData('logout_at').'</b><br/>';
}
```

Comment: Now try to get customer order using customer id. If you have any doubt please let me know. Also if you want to keep customer log life time then just write a cron job and copy data from log table to your custom table and change the join table.Thanks

Comment: It is not providing output for all users .. only 4 - 5 results with log in and log out data.

Comment: It will provide all customer with their log in logout data . I am sure you are getting all customer list and only 4- 5 coustomer has log in log out date that means only 4- 5 customer has logged in.If your log cleaning is on then you need to copy data from log_customer table to custom_table. Create a php file at the root of magento directory where just write a custom query which will copy data from log_customer table to custom table.In this way you can store log data.

Comment: Okay Thanks Avik .. will try this